# Creating a Bar graph on JPanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, paint

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this? I'm pretty new to Java and I can't seem to get why this won't open the `JPanel` or the rectangles, or the strings. Nothing is being shown but it does compile.

Code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Graphing extends JPanel
{

   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
   }

   public Graphing()
   {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Nested Panels");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      frame.getContentPane();
      frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350,200));
      frame.pack();
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public void paintComponent (Graphics page)
   {            
      super.paintComponent (page);          
      final int HEIGHT = 10;

      page.setColor (Color.yellow);
      page.fillRect (50, 50, (7*10), HEIGHT);//1-10
      page.fillRect (50, 64, (5*10), HEIGHT);//11-20
      page.fillRect (50, 78, (0*10), HEIGHT);//21-30
      page.fillRect (50, 92, (1*10), HEIGHT);//31-40
      page.fillRect (50, 106, (9*10), HEIGHT);//41-50
      page.fillRect (50, 120, (12*10), HEIGHT);//51-60
      page.fillRect (50, 134, (4*10), HEIGHT);//61-70
      page.fillRect (50, 148, (6*10), HEIGHT);//71-80
      page.fillRect (50, 162, (2*10), HEIGHT);//81-90
      page.fillRect (50, 176, (13*10), HEIGHT);//91-100

      page.drawString("1-10",10,60);
      page.drawString("11-20",10,74);
      page.drawString("21-30",10,88);
      page.drawString("31-40",10,102);
      page.drawString("41-50",10,116);
      page.drawString("51-60",10,130);
      page.drawString("61-70",10,144);
      page.drawString("71-80",10,158);
      page.drawString("81-90",10,172);
      page.drawString("91-100",10,186);

      page.drawString("7", 30, 60);
      page.drawString("5", 30, 74);
      page.drawString("0", 30, 88);
      page.drawString("1", 30, 102);
      page.drawString("9", 30, 116);
      page.drawString("12", 30, 130);
      page.drawString("4", 30, 144);
      page.drawString("6", 30, 158);
      page.drawString("2", 30, 172);
      page.drawString("13", 30, 186);
   }

}
```

Comment: 1. Your main method is empty, `public static void main (String[] args){}`. Come on now. You can fix this, I'm sure.

Comment: 2. You never add `this`, your Graphing JPanel, to anything. Add it to your JFrame. Read the tutorials as it beats guessing any time. Find them here: [Swing Info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info).

Comment: Hey guys, I'm sorry, as I mentioned I'm pretty new to this. Could you show me what you mean?

Answer (score 5):

```
public Graphing()   {
  JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Nested Panels");
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

  frame.getContentPane().add(this);
```

in main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Graphing();
}
```

To be fully Kosher, the main method should actually be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
           new Graphing();
        }
    });
}
```

While at this point, you don't have to know the details of this second main method code, but do know that it ensures that the Swing GUI is called on the main Swing thread. Doing this can help avoid unpredictable threading problems that are not likely to occur in your simple program, but can occur if your code gets a little more complex.

Other issues -- you'll want to try to avoid using magic numbers, hard-coded numbers, and instead use variables which will allow you to more easily change the heights of your bars.